# Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'HTMLOptionElement | HTMLOptGroupElement'

Tags: angular

I'm writing a blog management demo. I have to create a form to edit all the information about the available blog and change this data in API. This is the structure of API

```json
    {
    "title": "Trump lại dọa 'xóa sổ' Iran bằng lực lượng ",
    "des": "Tổng thống Mỹ lên án những bình luận \"xúc phạm\" của Iran và cảnh báo sẽ \"xóa sổ\" nước này nếu họ thực hiện bất cứ cuộc tấn công nào.",
    "detail": "\"Những phát biểu vô cùng ngu ngốc và xúc phạm mà Iran đưa ra hôm nay chỉ thể hiện rằng họ không hiểu thực tế. Bất cứ cuộc tấn công nào của Iran nhắm tới Mỹ đều sẽ vấp phải lực lượng vĩ đại và áp đảo. Trong một số trường hợp, áp đảo đồng nghĩa với xóa sổ\", Tổng thống Mỹ Donald Trump hôm nay viết trên Twitter. ",
    "category": 1,
    "public": true,
    "data_pubblic": "2019-06-12",
    "position": [
      1
    ],
    "thumbs": "https://i-vnexpress.vnecdn.net/2019/06/25/president-trump-02-gty-jef-190-3586-8058-1561478000.jpg",
    "id": 4},{
    "title": "Giá Bitcoin mất hơn 3.000 USD một ngày",
    "des": "Vừa chạm đỉnh 17 tháng sáng hôm qua (27/6), giá tiền kỹ thuật số phổ biến nhất thế giới  đã lao dốc.",
    "detail": "Cách đây vài giờ, giá Bitcoin chỉ còn 10.314 USD một đồng, giảm tới 3.600 USD so với đỉnh 17 tháng hôm qua. Hiện tại, mỗi đồng giao dịch quanh 11.460 USD. Hôm qua, Bitcoin có lúc mất hơn 1.700 USD chỉ trong 15 phút. Việc mất giá diễn ra khi sàn giao dịch tiền ảo hàng đầu thế giới Coinbase gặp sự cố. Trên CNBC, người phát ngôn Coinbase cho biết website của họ không thể truy cập \"trong thời gian ngắn vì khối lượng giao dịch lớn\".Dù vậy, giới chuyên gia cũng nhận định đà tăng của Bitcoin gần đây không bền vững. \"Kể cả những người lạc quan nhất vào tiền số cũng sẽ nói rằng mức tăng hơn 50% một tuần là quá nhanh, quá nhiều\", CEO Michael Moro của Genesis Global Trading cho biết. Ông khẳng định \"lực đẩy chính\" đằng sau diễn biến này là việc nhà đầu tư dùng đòn bẩy (vay nợ) để giao dịch. ",
    "category": 2,
    "public": true,
    "data_pubblic": "2019-06-04",
    "position": [
      1
    ],
    "thumbs": "https://i-kinhdoanh.vnecdn.net/2019/06/28/bit-4750-1561686878.jpg",
    "id": 5
  },
```

I used binding 2-way data in Angular and [(ngModel)] to display the data to the form but because i don't know how to use [(ngModel)] in  and many websites told me that use [(value)] but when i add it to my form, the error told that "Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'HTMLOptionElement | HTMLOptGroupElement'." but when i delete it, the error doesn't appear
This is my form.
I am a newbie so I hope that pp can help me this time. Thanks a lot
this is my form:

```html
<form [formGroup]="userFormGroup" *ngIf="blog" novalidate>
<div class="form-group selected">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Loại</label>
    <select class="form-control" 
    [ngModel]="category[blog.category]" [(value)]="category[blog.category]" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" #category required formControlName="category">
      <option value=1>Thời sự</option>
      <option value=2>Thế giới</option>
      <option value=3>Kinh Doanh</option>
      <option value=4>Giải trí</option>
      <option value=5>Pháp luật</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

And this is my edit-blog.component.ts, it will update and get data from id, thanks

```js
export class EditBlogComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() blog: Blog = new Blog();
  userFormGroup!: FormGroup;
  category = ['Thời sự', 'Thế giới', 'Kinh doanh', 'Giải trí', 'Pháp luật'];
  position = ['Việt Nam', 'Châu Á', 'Châu Âu', 'Châu Mỹ'];
  constructor(
    private BlogService: BlogServiceService,
    private location: Location,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  load(): void {
    window.location.reload();
  }
  getMovieFromRoute(): void {
    const id = +Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.BlogService.getBlogFromId(id).subscribe((blog) => (this.blog = blog));
    console.log(this.blog);
  }
  save(): void {
    this.BlogService.updateBlog(this.blog).subscribe(() => this.goBack());
    alert('update blog succesfully');
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMovieFromRoute();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing use one thing either `formControlName` or `ngModel` as you are interested in `ngModel` so remove `formControlName` from your `select`.

Options contains values , select itself don't have value

For `ngModel` use two way binding , like this `[(ngModel)]`

If you are using `ngModel` within `FormGroup` then add `ngModelOptions` value set `true`
Instead of using category[blog.category] within ngModel I would prefer this way

**Typescript**

```
selectedValue : string = "";
ngOnInit()
 {
          this.selectedValue  = category[....] // Select relevant value , convert in string
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="userFormGroup" *ngIf="blog" novalidate>
<div class="form-group selected">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Loại</label>
    <select class="form-control" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"  
    id="exampleFormControlSelect1" 
    #category 
    required 
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
      <option value=1>Thời sự</option>
      <option value=2>Thế giới</option>
      <option value=3>Kinh Doanh</option>
      <option value=4>Giải trí</option>
      <option value=5>Pháp luật</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```